# how can i avoid generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot a function in python but I can't seem to do it. I am running the following code, but I get an error that says I can't multiply a generator and a float together. Where is this coming from?

```
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t=0.1
cd=t*exp(-t/2)
tau=10
nt=100
v=0.01
w=0.9
u=0.4
s0=10
p=5

for i in range (1,10):
    sigma= u/(w+(s0/(p*cd)))
    print(sigma)
    C= lambda ksi: cd * (1-exp(((u-w * sigma)/v)*ksi))
    plt.plot([-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1],[C(i for i in range (-10,-1))])
    plt.xlabel(ksi)
    plt.ylabel(concentration)
    plt.title("tumeur avec regénessence")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    t+=tau/nt
```

this is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ilyes\Downloads\tumeur_avec_regénesence.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.plot([-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1],[C(i for i in range (-10,-1))])
  File "C:\Users\ilyes\Downloads\tumeur_avec_regénesence.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    C= lambda ksi: cd * (1-exp(((u-w * sigma)/v)*ksi))
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'generator'
```

Comment: i advice you to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I think you've omitted the actual error message

Answer (score 2):

use

```
plt.plot([-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1],[C(i) for i in range (-10, 0)])
```

instead of

```
plt.plot([-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1],[C(i for i in range (-10,-1))])
```

explanation: you want to apply `C` on each value not on the hole list at once. 
range(-10,-1) gives you values `-10 <= v < -1` but you want -1 to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tau=10
nt=100
v=0.01
w=0.9
u=0.4
s0=10
p=5

ksi = np.arange(-10,0)

for t in np.arange(1,10)*tau/nt:
    cd = t*np.exp(-t/2)
    sigma = u/(w+(s0/(p*cd)))
    C = lambda ksi: cd * (1-np.exp(((u-w * sigma)/v)*ksi))

    plt.plot(ksi, C(ksi), label=f"t = {t}")

plt.xlabel("ksi")
plt.ylabel("concentration")
plt.title("tumeur avec regénessence")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```